# Accessing Multiple records at a time in a loop in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a scenario: There are multiple records accommodated in a collection list and each record is being passed into a loop of operations. Since there are multiple records in a list and each records is being processed one by one. Now my requirement is to process every record at one time.

Can Any one suggest me that?

help is really appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify, perhaps with some sample code?  At the moment you seem to be saying "I am processing records one by one.  How can I process them one by one?" which makes no sense to me.

Comment: Process mens what operation ? INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/DROP/TRUNCATE/etc///

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about updating all records in collection at once, then bulk processing in PL/SQL is something that may help you. [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52plsql-1709862.html) is the reference that explains it.

```
FORALL indx IN 1 .. collection.COUNT
    UPDATE table
       SET table.column = new value for all columns
     WHERE table.column = condition;
```

Please note that normal loops will do context switch, but above snippet does context switch once.